# WordPress, шаблоны для архивных страниц

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, cms, acf

На сайте на WordPress есть зарегистрированный новый тип записи и таксономий.

Планирую, что страница архива этого типа записи будет использовать шаблона типа `archive-$posttype.php`, а страницы архивов для таксономий будут использовать шаблон типа `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php`.

На каждой странице архива, кроме вывода постов, есть отдельный контентный блок, текстовое содержимое которого индивидуальное для каждой архивной страницы.

Суть вопроса в том, что если шаблоны архивных страниц сделаны таким образом, как описал: `archive-$posttype.php`, `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php`, то каким образом вывести этот текстовый блок в админку, чтобы можно было его наполнять?

Или при таком варианте это будет не возможно сделать?

Comment: Вариантов масса. Можешь создать отдельные страницы для описаний каждого типа поста и тянуть в шаблоне контент с них, можешь создать 1 страницу для всех описаний и просто распихать их в разные поля и тянуть описания уже из этих полей, можешь вынести эти поля в кастомайзер

Comment: Но наверное логичней будет создать для каждого типа какую-то дефолтную рубрику, назначать ее всем постам этого типа и выводить на странице архива ее описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создание каких либо записей ведет за собой создание страницы, что (наверное) не очень хорошо для сеошной(или как там называют) массы сайта.

ACF Предлагает создание страниц [опций](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/), они не создаются как отдельные записи и не имеют url. Такую страниц можно создать в виде под меню к записям или страницам и добавить туда необходимые блоки контента для вывода на страницах архивов!

Если сайт мультиязычный, то для перевода страниц опций можно использовать плагин ACF Options for Polylang, если вы уже используете для мультиязычности плагин Polylang.